# Ways to intercept recent app (task manager button) on android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, launcher

I have tried intercepting the recent app button using one of the android lifecycle hook (onUserLeaveHint) and it has been working in android 11. After updating to android 12 due to the changes in behavior in launcher application that doesn't work anymore. I noticed that some mobile manager application are able to intercept the recent button.

Anybody can provide any insights on how to update my old launcher application to make it work on android 12.

Additional information: I am using a Samsung test phone, Thank You in advance.